# Lightning clientwidth of component when resize

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, aura

I have problem with geting width of component - I run resizer and try consol log with width of lightning button.

```
    component.set('v.resizeCallback', $A.getCallback(function(){
        if(component.isValid()) {
            console.log('component valid');
            var containerWidth =component.find('container').getElement().clientWidth);
            var countOfWidth = 0;

            var itemsArray= component.find('elementId');
            for (var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
                countOfWidth += itemsArray[i].get('v.clientWidth');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('component not valid');
        }
    }));
    window.addEventListener('resize', component.get('v.resizeCallback'));
```

Hm, I try dynamicly show or hide arrow to scrrool elements in container. I perfect run resizer ewent and when I resize window have properly width of container ('**container**') - value is in containerWidth.

Then I get all of element in container - all of them have this same id - ('**elementId**') - I have 13 elements. and I have array with them in **itemsArray** variable

All of items with elementId are Lightning:button !!!

And I need get width from it but I can't.

I try looping for them to get

Edit: 
idea of component:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="item2" type="Object" />

    <div>
        <div aura:id="container">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.item.array}" var="item">
                <lightning:button aura:id="elementId" label="{!item.label}" />
            </aura:iteration>
        <div>


        <div>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.item2.array}" var="item">
                <lightning:button aura:id="elementId2" label="{!item.label}" />
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? please update your post accordingly so we can better understand and help. thanks

Comment: Done update descryption;

Comment: are there any errors in your console when attempting to get the width? what Api version is your component using?

Comment: So when I use this code i have undefined, but when I try for example 
console.log('error: ' ,itemsArray[i].getElement())    , console.log('error: ' ,itemsArray[i].getElement().clientWidth)

i don't have eny console.log so i think this is crash. I use 41 Api


I try get('v.clientWidth') , get('v.body') - in this I can display object but i cant get anything from it

I don't now how I should get clientWidth from lightning component but when I use html div this working: component.find('container').getElement().clientWidth);

Comment: I can add only concept of it. 
Yes i have in iteration this same id because in lightning I can't create dynamic aura:id